# react-admin provider for aggregated data

Tags: reactjs, tabs, react-admin

I have a list of resources, which I understood that must be the entities for which we have the CRUD operations:

The problem is that inside the entity page I want to use 2 tabs (components), one for the list of the entity and one for a list of aggregated data based on the entity. The problem is with the second, because I was required to write a custom graphql query, but both components use the same source (first list).

```
<ProtectedResource 
     name={RESOURCES.Product} 
     list={Product.homepage} 
     icon={StarHalfIcon} 
     options={{ label: translate('Products') }}
/>
```

Products.js is a hook which returns this:

```
<TabbedForm redirect={`/${RESOURCES.Product}`}>
  <FormTab label={translate('Lines')}>
    <ReferenceManyField reference={RESOURCES.Product} target="" label="" fullWidth {...paginationProps('id')}>
         <ProductsList {...props} />
    </ReferenceManyField>
  </FormTab>
  <FormTab label={translate('Aggregated Lines')} path="/aggregates">
    <ReferenceManyField reference={RESOURCES.Product} target="" label="" fullWidth {...paginationProps('id')}>
         <ProductAggregatesList {...props} />
    </ReferenceManyField>
  </FormTab>
</TabbedForm>
```

In reality, should hit 2 queries: getAllProducts and getAggregatedProducts. Based on fetchType and resource, I can rewrite the query which I want to execute (in frontend), but I can not catch the data and send to the specific component.

```
if (fetchType === GET_MANY_REFERENCE && resource === RESOURCES.Product) 
   return getAggregatedProducts(resource, params);
```

And `GET_LIST` fetch type will be used for first tab.
If I create another resource, for `AggregatedProducts`, there will throw an error because `AggregatedProducts` is not known in backend's schema.